# Is it possible to derive a Generic instance of a recursive datatype?

Tags: purescript

I'm playing about with some types and the PureScript compiler. These are the types I've created (liberally stolen from [purescript-dsl-example](https://github.com/coot/purescript-dsl-example)):

```
newtype User = User
  { id :: Int
  , name :: String
  }

data Command a = Add User a
               | Remove Int a
               | ChangeName Int String a
```

This type checks and compiles. Then, thinking it might be useful to be able to serialise these types into JSON, I installed `purescript-foreign-generic` and added this:

```
derive instance genericCommand :: Generic Command _
```

As a first step towards a Show instance.

The type checker then throws this error:

```
Error found:
in module Main
at src/Main.purs:33:43 - 33:50 (line 33, column 43 - line 33, column 50)

  Could not match kind

    Type

  with kind

    Type -> Type


while checking the kind of Generic Command (Sum (Constructor "Add" (Product ... ...)) (Sum (Constructor "Remove" ...) (Constructor "ChangeName" ...)))
in value declaration genericCommand
```

Is there a way to derive a Generic instance from my type? If not, is there a way I can write a Generic instance manually? I have no idea what that would entail, so am okay with admitting I'm not sure if that last question even makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's possible to derive `Generic` for your type, you're just not using the correct syntax. It should be like this:

```
derive instance genericCommand :: Generic (Command a) _
```

When you write `Generic Command _`, the `Command` part (which is the first parameter of `Generic`) has kind `Type -> Type` - that is, if you apply `Command` to a `Type`, then you get a `Type`. So, for example, `Command Int` will have the kind `Type`. But `Command` itself has kind `Type -> Type`.

But the `Generic` class expects the first argument of kind `Type`, not `Type -> Type`, that's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: Nice, it being a silly syntactical error on my part is the best outcome. I had tried `Generic Command _ _` and `Generic Command a a` so I'm not sure I understand the use of `_` here, but that's another question.